# Iam getting bad thoughts and insults about allah

Tags: allah, waswasa

Assalamualikum,
i am a 20 year old muslim boy. I am facing a problem from several days. I get bad thoughts and insults about allah and his prophet in my mind. I get very bad words about allah and i feel depressed after having such thoughts. These thoughts keep constantly coming to my mind whenever i pray salah ;and also in other times. Earlier these thoughts used to come only in salah but now they come all the time. I am also not sure whether i say these bad words in mind or did i utter it slowly because i have a habit of saying things to myself. I dont know how to deal with these thoughts. Will i be accountable for these thoughts (the thoughts are very bad sometimes i feel like i may lose eeman because of these thoughts). Thats why i am sending you this problem so i that i ca get help regarding this. Please provide me a detailed answer whether iamaccoountable for these thoughts or not and if iam accountable then how should i repent for it. I hope you will answer me soon because my anxiety is increasing day by day.

Answer (score 0):

This is the waswasa from the Satan. Whenever you have these thoughts say 'Auzubulliah'. He is always trying to make disconnection between you and Allah. Some tips to stop these

1. Do Zikr of Allah because it keeps your towards Allah.
2. Try to be in wudu it gives protection from Satan.
3. Never forget Allah because it's the target of Satan.
4. Watch YouTube videos about Islam and hear lectures of Islamic scholars.
   I give you a link of videos series that will build your faith about Allah
   https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpbPLDjlfpaCMdicwFbKpiM5G2o_8Ce6p